# how to get matched group number in pcre2

Tags: pcre

I want to use pcre2 to match string.
For example, I have several string pattern, "a","b","c","d", and "e".
I have a long text "str" to match.
Now I construct a pattern "a|b|c|d|e"  to match "str" use pcre2_match.
How to know which pattern is matched?
I just want to get the matched pattern number, not "a" or "b", as I don't want to compare the matched pattern with "a","b","c","d","e" again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the PCRE2 library directly and have access to all of its features, you have several solutions for this, from the simplest to the most involved:

- Use numbered capture groups: `(a)|(b)|(c)|(d)`
- Use named capture groups: `(?<a>a)|(?<b>b)|(?<c>c)|(?<d>d)`
- Use [marks](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2api.html#SEC2): `a(*MARK:a)|b(*MARK:b)|c(*MARK:c)|d(*MARK:d)`
- Use [callouts](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2callout.html): `a(?C{a})|b(?C{b})|c(?C{c})|d(?C{d})`
- If you *really* can't modify your input pattern, use `PCRE2_AUTO_CALLOUT` and find some way to map pattern offsets to branches, then rememeber the last pattern offset seen before the end of the match

Comment: By using numbered capture groups: (a)|(b)|(c)|(d) ， how can I get the number of matched group? Where is it stored?

Comment: @johnhypo it's in the [match data block](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2api.html#SEC27), more precisely in the *ovector*. Read aboit it [here](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2api.html#SEC30). You can tell if the capture group number **n** matched if `ovector[2*n] != PCRE2_UNSET`. **n** starts at 1, as the index 0 designates the full pattern. Alternatively, you can use the return value of `pcre2_match`, which is the highest captured group number which has been set.

Comment: a little correction: the return value of `pcre2_match` is **1+** the highest captured group number.